# How do I intercept HTTP traffic on OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, pf

I saw this tutorial: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html and I tried to implement a part of it on OS X 10.10. One command used there is

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
```

How do I achieve the same using pf?

Comment: That's a NAT redirect rule, that in PF would be achieved using the syntax `nat on $ext_if from $int_if:network to any -> ($ext_if)` .. but your question is WRT "intercepting HTTP" traffic, which is a completely different set of PF rules .. what specifically are you trying to do to the traffic? A bandwidth queue, a proxy, something else?

Comment: I am trying to redirect traffic passing through my laptop to a squid proxy running on localhost, just like in the linked tutorial. In other words, I am trying to set up an intercepting proxy